# Location tracking in the background Android

Tags: java, android, gps, position, foreground

I got some problems to keep a location tracking for my Android app.
The service we developed are all working, but depending on the phones and the API level, they are killed soon or later.

My purpose is to notify a user when he is getting out of a certain range, and this is working when the app is running.

This is the service that calculates when the user is in or out of the zone:

```
public class GeoFenceService extends BaseService {

@Inject
GeoFenceRepository geoFenceRepository;
SettingValueService settingValueService = new SettingValueService();
GeoFence geoFence;
private GeofencingClient mGeofencingClient;
PendingIntent mGeofencePendingIntent;
List<Geofence> mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<>();

public GeoFenceService() {
    super();
    Injector.getInstance().getAppComponent().inject(this);
}

public Observable<GeoFence> saveGeofence(GeoFence geoFence) {
    if (geoFence.getId() == null)
        geoFence.setId(CommonMethods.generateUuid());
    commitToRealm(geoFence);
    if (Application.getHasNetwork())
        return geoFenceRepository.saveGeofence(geoFence);
    else
        return Observable.just(null);
}

public Observable<GeoFence> getGeofence() {
    return geoFenceRepository.getGeofence();
}

public GeoFence getGeofenceFromRealm() {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmQuery<GeoFence> query = realm.where(GeoFence.class);
    GeoFence result = query.findFirst();
    if (result != null)
        return realm.copyFromRealm(result);
    return null;
}

public void initGeoFence(Context context) {
    SettingValue autoCloking = settingValueService.getSettingByName("auto_clocking");
    if (autoCloking != null && autoCloking.getValue().equals("true")) {
        if (mGeofencingClient == null)
            mGeofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(context);
        geoFence = getGeofenceFromRealm();
        if (geoFence != null) {
            addGeofence(geoFence, context);
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void addGeofence(GeoFence geofence, Context context) {
        mGeofenceList.clear();//only 1 geofence at the same time.
        mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId(geofence.getId())

                .setCircularRegion(
                        geofence.getLatitude(),
                        geofence.getLongitude(),
                        (float) geofence.getRadius()
                )
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setLoiteringDelay(30000)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                        Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL)
                .build());
        mGeofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(), getGeofencePendingIntent(context));
}

private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent(Context context) {
    // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
    if (mGeofencePendingIntent != null) {
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GeofencingService.class);
    // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
    // calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
    mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
            FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    return mGeofencePendingIntent;
}

private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER | GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}

public void removeGeofence(Context context) {
    if (mGeofencingClient != null)
        mGeofencingClient.removeGeofences(getGeofencePendingIntent(context));
}
```

}

Even if this was working in the background we made a service to wake up the GPS of the phone every 60 sec following the advice of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28758609/how-to-update-gps-location-on-app-background-to-foreground/) question.

This is the service we made:

```
public class UpdateLocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "UpdateLocationService";
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 60000;
private Context mContext;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
    mContext = this;
    getLocation();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        if (googleApiClient != null) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void getLocation() {
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL);
    fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    if (googleApiClient != null) {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
//  Location location = 
fusedLocationProviderApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    fusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "User location :"+location.getLatitude()+" , "+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}



@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
}
}
```

and finally this is the call in our main activity:

```
 if (checkGpsProviderEnabled()) {
            geoFenceService.initGeoFence(this);
            Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, GeofencingService.class);
            startService(msgIntent);
            startService(new Intent(this,UpdateLocationService.class));
        }
```

Of course, we implement the authorization for Localisation and service déclaration in our AndroidManifest

And everything is working fine when the app isn't in the foreground

The foreground is working on some device but not all, and I wanted to know if I can do something more to force our services to run all the time in the background

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you get your app whitelisted from Doze mode this will never work when the screen goes off.  You realize that right?  (You cannot programmatically witelist yourself, you can at best ask the user to do it).

Comment: No i didn't know about Doze mode and yes it would explain why my device (api 22) is working and not the others.
Is there a way to ask the user to whiteliste my app ?

Comment: Yes. I'm mobile at the moment so looking it up will have to wait, but there's a page I settings they can do it on. You can launch that page for them

Comment: Ok i'll look in the documentation about that
But is there a better way to accomplish what i try to do with localisation in the background ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32627342/how-to-whitelist-app-in-doze-mode-android-6-0

Comment: thanks a lot i'll try it